# Sales Force Search Form - How do i submit the keyword without the pram name

Tags: html, salesforce

I'm trying to get the following to return

```
"https://harpercollege.force.com/Question/s/global-search/search+keyword"
```

instead of

```
"https://harpercollege.force.com/Question/s/global-search/?search=search+keyword".
```

```html
    <form action="https://harpercollege.force.com/Question/s/global-search/">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript to open a URL + the text input by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451513/javascript-to-open-a-url-the-text-input-by-user)

Answer (score 0):

You could try intercepting the `submit` event before the form is actually submitted and rewrite the default form action like this perhaps:

```js
let form=document.forms['usr-search'];
    form.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',e=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      form.action+=[ form.search.name, form.search.value ].join('+');
      form.submit();
    })
```

```html
<form name='usr-search' action="https://harpercollege.force.com/Question/s/global-search/">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change the action of the form submit. It still returned with the "?search=" in the URL.

Comment: Can you mark it as a duplicate and redirect it to here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451513/javascript-to-open-a-url-the-text-input-by-user